# The grouping of the keys by name

Tags: c#, grouping, key, couchbase

I use couchbase service to store temporary information. Here is my problem:
I have many pairs of key-value, but they are, however, conventionally divided into groups (key1_ *; key2_ *; key3_ *). For example the pair would looks like:

"key1_1":"value1";  "key1_2":"value2";  "key1_3":"value3";
"key2_1":"value4";  "key2_2":"value5";  "key2_3":"value6";
"key3_1":"value7";  "key3_2":"value8";  "key3_3":"value9";

I need to send an request that will be used to return information about the availability of values ​​for any of these groups: for example:

var info = client.Get ("key1_ *") or something like that. Is there any filter in the names of keys, or are any options for grouping, which could solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

In couchbase 2.0 you can use Views. You can store json object in database, so key-val pair should look like:

```
key:<guid>; value: {id:<guid>, group<int>, data<your_values_type>}
```

Where group is an equivalent to key1_*;
Then create a view with 
Map:

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.group, [doc.id, doc.group, doc.data]);
}
```

You've get key-value pairs of such format:

```
key: <int>group ; value: <array>[id,group,data]
```

then you can filter results by key by adding "?key=" to request. Or if you use some api libs, i.e. .net api, you can do it from your code:

```
Client.GetView<Int64>(Couchbase.Configuration.DevelopmentModeNameTransformer.NamePrefix + "MyViewName", "MyViewName").Key(<desired_key>)
```